# Operator norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Any help here would be appreciated. Very new and rusty to more serious functional analysis.

Compute the operator norm of $ A = \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     a & 0 \\
     0 & b
  \end{array} \right]$

where $A \in  Hom(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \mathbb{R}^{2})$ w.r.t to the $||.||_3$ norm for the domain and the $||.||_2$ norm for the codomain.

Where $ ||x||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_i|^{2}}$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=(x,y)$. We want to estimate $\Vert Av\Vert_2=\Vert (ax,by)\Vert_2$ in terms of $\Vert(x,y)\Vert_3$. Using Holder inequality, we get
\begin{align*}
\Vert (ax,by)\Vert_2&=\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2}=\sqrt{(a^2,b^2)\cdot(x^2,y^2)}\\
&\leq\sqrt{\Vert(a^2,b^2)\Vert_3}\sqrt{\Vert(x^2,y^2)\Vert_{3/2}}=(a^6+b^6)^{\frac{1}{6}}\Vert(x,y)\Vert_3
\end{align*}
Moreover, we can choose $x$ and $y$ (depending on $a$, $b$) such that the Holder inequality becomes an equality.

Hence $$\Vert A\Vert_{(\mathbb{R}^2,\Vert\cdot\Vert_3)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R}^2,\Vert\cdot\Vert_2)}= (a^6+b^6)^{\frac{1}{6}}$$